# How do i set up AMPache on a hosted site

Tags: hosting

I am able to set it up locally but would like to host it on my own website.

Comment: Documentation: http://ampache.org/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set apache up on a website, only on a server. Apache is an application that handles http requests on your ip, so installing it makes having a website possible.

Comment: im sorry i had a typo but i meant AMPache

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://ampache.org/wiki/install) looks pretty straight forward (assuming that you have the requirements - Webserver, PHP, MySQL).

Just download the Stable version, extract it (following the Extraction section) and then follow the rest of the install instructions (replacing localhost with whatever the URL for your website is - eg. example.com).